# Retrieving distinct record using join in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am running a sql query using two tables namely `QuestionInsert` and `Question_Papers`.
The columns in th erespective table are as follows:-

```
Table:-QuestionInsert  
Columns:-QuestionNum,Question,Answer,CatId,SubCatId

Table:-Question_Papers  
Columns:-QuestionNum
```

1. I want an sql query which will retrieve all QuestionNum,Question,Answer from table QuestionInsert which QuestionNum is present in table Question_Papers.
2. Also, I want to retrieve all QuestionNum,Question,Answer from table QuestionInsert which QuestionNum is not present in table Question_Papers.

This data is displayed on a Grid View.The queries I am using are as follows:- 
The Query for first condition is:

```
SELECT F.QuestionNum,
       F.Question,
       F.Answer 
FROM QuestionInsert F 
INNER JOIN Question_Papers FS ON F.[QuestionNum]=FS.QuestionNum 
WHERE ((F.QuestionNum=FS.QuestionNum) AND (F.CatId='" + 
DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' And F.SubCatId='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'))  
ORDER BY F.QuestionNum DESC;
```

The other query for 2nd condition. is:-

```
SELECT F.QuestionNum,
       F.Question,
       F.Answer 
FROM QuestionInsert F INNER JOIN Question_Papers FS ON F.[QuestionNum]!=FS.QuestionNum 
WHERE ((F.QuestionNum!=FS.QuestionNum) AND (F.CatId='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' 
And F.SubCatId='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'))  
ORDER BY F.QuestionNum DESC
```

My code is retrieving correct information but if more than one row of same `QuestionNum` is present in `Question_Papers` table, it is displaying all the rows repeatedly. I want to display the unique rows which are present and not present in table Question_Papers separately.

Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you tried using `DISTINCT`? Also read up on [Sql Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Comment: Yes I tried! It is not acceptable with joins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following for the second condition:

```
SELECT F.QuestionNum,F.Question,F.Answer 
FROM QuestionInsert F 
WHERE (F.CatId='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' And F.SubCatId='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "')
AND F.QuestionNum NOT IN (SELECT QuestionNum FROM Question_Papers)
ORDER BY F.QuestionNum DESC
```

And this for the first condition:

```
SELECT F.QuestionNum,F.Question,F.Answer 
FROM QuestionInsert F  
WHERE (F.CatId='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' 
AND F.SubCatId='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "') 
AND F.QuestionNum IN (SELECT QuestionNum FROM Question_Papers)
ORDER BY F.QuestionNum DESC";
```

However, there are serious problems with your code - have you looked into [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)? There are many data access frameworks, like [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework), that would push you down a better route.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This query is giving an error for the first condition "The multi-part identifier "FS.questionNum" could not be bound."

Comment: I tried the query for the second condition and used the same query by removing "NOT" for the first condition and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Good, glad it helped. However, please look at the other points I made. Plus look at naming conventions. If I look at code with field names like DropDownList1 I feel sad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first query can be rewritten using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT F.QuestionNum,F.Question,F.Answer FROM QuestionInsert F 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Question_Papers P WHERE P.QuestionNum = F.QuestionNum)
AND F.CatId='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' 
AND F.SubCatId='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'
```

Second query using `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT F.QuestionNum,F.Question,F.Answer FROM QuestionInsert F 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Question_Papers P WHERE P.QuestionNum = F.QuestionNum)
AND F.CatId='" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' 
AND F.SubCatId='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'
```

---

Please note that with the way those queries are written (which was taken from your question), you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should use parameters instead.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But this query is returning all the data from table QuestionInsert.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you had additional conditions. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a need to use a `join` nor a reason for repeating the join clause within `where`. Form what I can gather all you need to do is check for existence, which recent versions (2005+) of sql server supports with [`EXISTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx). Doing this as a single query than a correlated subquery can be used to check and flag existence

```sql
DECLARE @question_insert TABLE ( id INT, question VARCHAR(50), answer VARCHAR(50), catid INT, subcatid INT )
DECLARE @question_paper TABLE ( id INT, question_insert_id INT )

INSERT INTO @question_insert ( id, question, answer, catid, subcatid )
VALUES 
    (1, 'How old are you?', '20', 1, 1),
    (2, 'Who was the first president?', '?', 2, 1)

INSERT INTO @question_paper ( id, question_insert_id )
VALUES (1, 1),(2, 1)

SELECT
    qi.id,
    qi.question,
    qi.answer,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @question_paper qp 
                     WHERE qp.question_insert_id = qi.id) 
         THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS in_question_paper
FROM @question_insert qi
--WHERE qi.catid=@catid AND qi.subcatid=@subcatid
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/11633)

Alternatively AS individual queries

```sql
SELECT
    qi.id,
    qi.question,
    qi.answer,
    'Yes' AS in_question_paper
FROM @question_insert qi
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @question_paper qp 
             WHERE qp.question_insert_id = qi.id)
```

And

```sql
SELECT
    qi.id,
    qi.question,
    qi.answer,
    'No' AS in_question_paper
FROM @question_insert qi
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @question_paper qp 
                 WHERE qp.question_insert_id = qi.id)
```

I will reiterate that you should read up on [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx) and not concatenate user input into queries.

Also re. `DISTINCT` not being "acceptable in joins" that is not the case. What is not acceptable is to use `DISTINCT` and refer to a column that is not part of select list in another part of the query (in this case it would've been the `WHERE` clause), a way round this is to use `GROUP BY` instead.